# Checking if android emulator is using KVM accelation or not?

Tags: android, android-emulator

As per the documentation on [Check if a hypervisor is installed](https://developer.android.com/studio/run/emulator-acceleration#hypervisors), I ran the command

> ./Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator --aceel-check

and it outputs

> emulator: ERROR: No AVD specified. Use '@foo' or '-avd foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'

instead of

> accel:
> 0
> KVM (version 12) is installed and usable.

I already have installed and verified the KVM installation by following [ubuntu KVM installation.](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/KVM/Installation)

```
$ virsh list --all
Id   Name   State
--------------------
```

I also do have a working android emulator (Nexus 6).

**So is there any way that I can know that my emulator is using KVM or not?**

Answer (score 2):

Only one dash to start the argument. Should be `./Android/Sdk/emulator/emulator -accel-check`